# Python 3to2 Tool - Requires At Least

Tags: python, macos, file-conversion

So, I'm using `3to2` to port my Python 3.3 code back to version 2.x.  I, believe, I correctly installed 3to2 by downloading the .tar.gz, `cd` to the file and running `python3.3 setup.py build` and then `python3.3 setup.py install`, so I don't think that is what is causing the issue.

The issue:  the issue is that after I `cd` to the correct file, with the code I wish to use `3to2` on, I run `3to2 filename.py`, which then returns the following:

```
 Checking Python version info...
 ERROR: 3to2 requires at least Python 2.7 in the 2.x branch.
```

Now, I have Python 3.3 installed, which I did myself and Python 2.7, which came pre-installed on my [Mac - OSX Lion 10.7.3] computer.  Any ideas why this may be?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is pretty old, I figured I can still help if anyone else has this same issue.

- If you've installed 3to2 already, uninstall it.  I used pip, so if you did too, run a `pip uninstall 3to2`.
- If you're on OSX, do a quick `python --version` and make sure that your current version is 2.7.*.
- To get a working version of 3to2 run 'sudo python -m pip install 3to2'.

Now, when you run 3to2, it will be referencing the correct python version.

Answer (score -1):

I feel your pain I spent the last hour troubleshooting this issue on my mac, below is what I did...

Open terminal, type :

```
brew install python
```

**note :** brew might mention that python is already installed, or that it's installed but unlinked... either way. Then type :

```
brew link --overwrite python

echo export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If this doesn't work try typing `brew doctor`, I would have never been able to fix my problem without it's feedback..

This fixed my problem, but there might another way...